# "Seek his benefit at the expense of yours". How to say that properly?

Tags: phrase-requests

I want to say that if someone truly loved you, he would not seek his benefit at the expense of yours.

How can I say that better than I did in the title of this question?

Answer (score 5):

I'd say "... he would not seek to profit at your expense."

Answer (score 1):

If you want something close to the way you phrased it, try "He would not seek to benefit at your expense."

Answer (score 0):

The concept identified is that of selflessness.

Answer (score 0):

"If he truly loved you, he would not assume your subservience."